# Multimedia keys stopped working

Tags: keyboard

Though correctly mapped, some of my multimedia keys stopped working on my ASUS 1215N (Ubuntu 10.10).
All Fn keys are working excepting the ones related to Rhythmbox (XF86AudioNext, XF86AudioPrev, XF86AudioStop, XF86AudioPlay/XF86AudioPause).

I cannot tell when this issue began or if any packages where updated before this occurred.

Anyone knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Same problem with *Logitech Media keyboard 600* on Lucid 64 bits. It works well for a while but suddenly stops working.<br>
If I restart the gnome session (*CONTROL + ALT + ←*), it works well again.<br>
Is it a bug? Which is the program responsible of this fail?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: “This question is unlikely to help any future visitors” — yeah. It was likely to help me (I’m having the same exact problem)…

Comment: @ArtyomKazak "if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is not abandoned, please flag the question explaining that."